# Parameterize a jQuery dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

This question is really using a jQuery dialog to ask a more generic jQuery question. In essence, I need to pass a continuation to a modal jQuery dialog.

I want to define a dialog box *once* on a page, but when calling `dialog('open')` on it, I want to arrange for the button functions in the dialog to have a value in scope that they can call back.

Given:

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .html('Is this text correctly segmented?')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Correct?',
                    buttons: { "Yes": function()   { $(this).dialog("close");
                                                   },
                               "No":   function() {  $(this).dialog("close");
                             }
              });
```

Could it be as simple as declaring some other variable, referencing it in the button functions,
and setting it before opening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is the following:

1. On your page, add a *div* element that acts as a drop target
2. In your method that opens a new dialog, create a new dialog with a random ID and append it to the drop target
3. Open the dialog programmatically

This will allow you to programmatically generate a new dialog, passing it the title, content, buttons, etc. without having to predefine it explicitly on the page.